# Android: What view is being rendered

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am currently looking at a sizeable android project that is not entirely mine.  As a result many time i'm not sure exactly what it is i'm looking at.  Is there a way to determine what view/views are currently being rendered in the emulator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hierarchy viewer would probably help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html